# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor de 2 columnas para realizar una cuenta matemática e imprimirlas en otra columna con el plugin datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Aca el ejemplo de como hago la tabla:

```html
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "filter": false,
            "responsive": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: 'tabla/productos',
                global: false,
                method: 'POST',
                data: function (d) {
                    d.campo = $('input[name=filter_campo]').val();
                    d.productos_nombres = $('select[name=filter_nombre]').val();
                    d.lineas_de_produccion = $('select[name=filter_linea_de_produccion]').val();
                    d.estados = $('select[name=filter_estados]').val();
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                    return meta.row+1;
                    }
                },
                {data: 1},
                {data: 2},
                {data: 3},
                {data: 4},
                {data: 5},
                {data: 6},
                {data: 7},
                {data: 8, searchable: false, 
                    render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                                
                        if (data) {
                            return '<input id="toggle" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activo" data-off="Inactivo" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
                        }else {
                            return '<input id="toggle" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox"         data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activo" data-off="Inactivo" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
                        }
                    }
                },
                {data: 0, searchable: false, 
                    render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                        return '<button type="button" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-warning "><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> <span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span></button> <button type="button" class="eliminar delete-modal btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Eliminar</span></button>';
                    }
                },
            ],
        });
```

Quiero obtener los datos de la posición 5 y 6 para sacar una cuenta y mostrar el resultado de la misma, pero la verdad no encuentro como hacerlo y ya he buscado de distintas maneras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi, de la siguiente manera:

```
{"render": function ( data, type, row ) {
     return row[12] + row[15];
}},
```